# update local storage value

Tags: html, local-storage

I want to reset the value of local storage form a from that user enter it's values.

I make default value

```
//default setting values
 localStorage.autoalert="false";
```

but when user submit a form this code is excuting

```
var activateAutoAlert=$("input[name='activateAutoAlert']").is(":checked")?"true":"false";
alert(activateAutoAlert);
localStorage.autoalert=String(activateAutoAlert);
```

the alert works and display "true" value, but the local storage still "false"!

How can I set variable value to a local storage .
I tried these ways

```
 localStorage.autoalert=activateAutoAlert;
 localStorage.autoalert=activateAutoAlert.toString();
```

and no one update the value of local storage. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/n4UhY/) is working fine for me:

```
localStorage.autoalert = "false";
window.alert(localStorage.getItem("autoalert"));
$("input[name='activateAutoAlert']").click(function() {
    var activateAutoAlert = $("input[name='activateAutoAlert']").is(":checked") ? "true" : "false";
    localStorage.autoalert = activateAutoAlert;
    alert(localStorage.autoalert);
});
```

Is the form submit reloading the same page?  How are you making sure your code to set `autoalert` to `false` isn't getting executed after the reload?

Comment: The same code works tonight, it seems that the chrome need to be closed an opened again to make the update process on local storage.